# Send() and recv() double or int

Tags: c++, winsock

I have problem with send and recv double/int from client to server and server to client.
For this moment, I have:

client:

```
cin>>xp;
send( master,(char*)&xp,sizeof(xp),0);
```

server:

```
int valread, nr;
char * buffer;   
valread = recv(s,(char *)&nr,sizeof(buffer),0);
```

and it's work, but when i send from server to client i do something wrong.

I have on server:

```
int lol;
lol=5;
send(s, (char*)&lol, sizeof(lol), 0);
```

And I want this int on client:

```
bytesRecv = recv(master,(char*)&nr,sizeof(buffer),0);
```

I don't knwo why it doesn't work :/ When I cout/printf this int on client it's 0 or 9,2555...
Please help :/

Comment: Sounds like [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem.

Comment: Why `sizeof (buffer)`? Why do you care how many bytes a `char *` takes up when your sending integers?

Comment: What protocol are you using? And why are you ignoring the return values of `send` and `recv`? What happens if you receive only one byte?

Comment: It's my mistake. I have this: bytesRecv = recv(mainSocket,(char*)&nr,sizeof(nr),0); but it's still not work. I use tcp

Answer (score 2):

Your `sizeof(buffer)` is wrong - you should send and receive a `sizeof(int)`.

Also, note this will not work if your server and client store integers in different order in memory - [their Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) may be different.

To make sure this is not a problem, switch from host to network order and back. Read about [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and [ntohl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl)

Comment: Ok, I improve this, but it still not work. I might add that I programming this on Win. But why send/recv client->server it work, but server->client no? Maybe you can give simple example on send/recv int from server to client?

Comment: ntohl exists on Windows, as well. However, if both your client and server are on Windows, endianness is not an issue.

Comment: Yes, my client and sever are on Win on the same computer

Comment: Use a debugger - what do you get in `bytesRecv` ?

Comment: Ok, it's work. When i send/recv integers. But what i must do that i want send/recv double?

Can I use:

server: `send(s, (char*)&koniec, sizeof(double), 0);`
client:  `recv(master,(char*)&nr,sizeof(double),0);`

? When I use this and use printf on client it doesn't work :/

Comment: Yes, it should work this way. Are you sure `nr` is double? Again, check `bytesRecv`.